# Lotus domino Agent on web query save

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I have developed a online survey that can be taken by anonymous user, they receive the link in their personal email ID.

However this works well on local server while replicated to main server I am getting below error :

Error 500

HTTP Web Server: Lotus Notes Exception - Error validating user's agent execution access

The form is represented to the user wherein they would click on next button to move next survey question, the form has allow public access ticked, and agent also has run as public user ticked in.

in database ACL as of anonymous has been set to manager access but it may reduced to Author or editor when it moves to final production.

The agent runs on web query save when user clicks on next button on the form.

Please assist.

Comment: Not sure what you clicked in agent. Please check "allow Public access users to view and run this agent" not "Run as Web user".

Also precise WHEN you are getting error (opening the link or clicking on next or on submit or ?)

Comment: I clicked on next button and in turn on next button the javascript is "document.forms[0].submit() ; which in turn calles the web query save agent and which in turn saves the current question answer and fatches the next question. the error I am getting on Next button. I already enabled allow to run as public user on agents property.

Comment: Please add the agent's code. My guess is that it's attempting to perform a restricted operation.

Comment: Yes that was the one, it worked, thanks Richard. and Emmanuel